Why would an ocean world prevent the creation of ocean bases but allow ships?
In my setting, modern day Earth is littered with portals leading to alternate Earths. This leads to extra-dimensional occupation from every country, leading to much competition. Most alternative Earths are uninhabited. This has made many nations incredibly resource-wealthy.
The nations' current contention is over an Earth with no landmass that is entirely covered in water, effectively an ocean world. Each nation sends aircraft carriers (resources are from looted Earths) to this hydro-Earth in an attempt to carve out their own territory, causing unending conflicts.
I want this world to prevent them from creating artificial islands, ocean bases, or any other ocean-based structures that gives them a steady footing on solid ground but still allow watercraft (such as the aircraft carriers) to navigate around. I'm trying to create a chaotic pirate-esque aesthetic where the nations are forced to only occupy this world by ship and create mobile thalassocracies in the most literal sense.
What would this ocean Earth need?

The real question is why would anybody bother with carving out territory in that world. Aircraft carriers etc. are expensive. What is the value proposition?

@AlexP Maybe another iteration of portals leading to worlds with greater inherent value?

This alternate Earth looks very much like Hydros, the setting of Silverberg's The Face of the Waters.

@AlexP: Lack of inconvenient prior inhabitants + the more-desirable Earths already being taken?

Important factor, how deep is the ocean. Probably the technology to mine iron ore from the ocean bottom is not very well developed.

Question - how are you going to do Maintenance and Dry-Dock your ships in this scenario. The Seas are a harsh mistress.

Note to people who vote VTC:Opinion-Based. On Worldbuilding, pretty much all questions are inherently "opinion-based." Therefore, my personal metric isn't whether or not there can be many answers, but whether or not the [help/dont-ask] "all answers having equal value" rule is breeches. There are enough rationalized answers already focusing on meeting the OP's specific expectations that best-answer judgements can (IMO) be made. Note that It's pretty rare for me to VTC:Opinion-Based because of all this.

@AlexP - fishing!

I agree with @AlexP. The reason why humans bother being on that planet at all would be really good to give better and more focused answers. Especially since humans have the tendency to make things possible (at least in the domain of engineering) as long as they are lucrative enough and the tendency not do stuff that is possible but not worthwhile.

If there are so many other planets to exploit, you would have to come up with a really good reason for this planet to be contentious or it will just be ignored and other countries will just go somewhere else.  Even if we wanted water, the cost of entering the planets gravity well and exiting would cause me to mine out every water containing asteroid first.

@TheDemonLord: Why, with a floating drydock, of course!

@Vikki - yep... and where does the floating dry dock go in to dry dock - because it too, needs maintenance and stuff done to it to repair the damage of the ocean.

@TheDemonLord: Those floating drydocks're built in multiple separable segments, each of which're seaworthy on their own.  So detach the segments and drydock each smaller segment in another floating drydock (with the segments turned sideways to fit).

@Vikki - Actually, that works really well! Awesome solution!

@datacube : and if the location is big, and interesting, but not worthwhile, then they will only station a few small token research teams, just to keep some presence there out of prestige, or for possible future claims if something worthwhile is discovered in the future. Just like with Antarctica. It would be technically possible to build big cities and immense military bases there, but it would be so expensive that nobody would want to pay for it, as there will be no advantage gained by doing so. So in the OPs world there is place for a few small research vessels, but not for any huge navies.

@TheDemonLord: Real-life floating drydocks're built like that as well, though I don't know if the segments of the real-life ones're short enough relative to their width to actually be able to fit inside another same-sized drydock if turned sideways.

Ocean based structures like bases and artificial islands still need something to be anchored to.
If the water is deep enough it is practically impossible to have anything anchored.
As long as the ocean in your world is deep and not shallow, you can float anywhere you like but you can never stand still.

Note that "deep enough" is really deep. We have petroleum extraction platforms operating in seas up to 2,500 m (8,000 ft) deep. Much deeper than that and it becomes debatable whether there is anything of value to conquer.

I don't see a requirement in the question that the base needs to stay in one place. Ocean structures in our world are put in specific places for specific reasons like resource extraction and need to stay there. In this setting, there are no landmasses to protect, and no real reason to extract resources here - there aren't really "strategic positions" other than where you are with respect to the other fleet. Why must the base be anchored? If you really need to stay put, just run the engines - it seems the setting has wild resource abundance.

@NuclearHoagie a base needs to have also a strategic relevance. Having it drift into enemy territory or far from where the fleet needs its support doesn't seem like a good situation

Floating in a particular location isn't impossible with some station keeping. Whether or not it is worth it depends on stuff like your energy budget, the currents, and how important the location is.

@AlexP some exoplanets like Kepler-138 c and Kepler-138 d have oceans that are at least 1,600 km deep.   Especially since this planet has no dry land, having oceans that are way deeper than humans can possibly reach the bottom of is perfectly plausible.

@L.Dutch: Put engines on the base, problem solved.

@Nosajimiki: Is a 1600-km-long anchor cable really that undoable, though?

It does raise the question of where to draw the line between base and ship

@Vikki It depends ... depending on your planet, that depth could easily be hot enough to melt steel, or at the very least make your cables so soft that they break.

@Vikki a long cable in the water also presents a huge surface for the ocean currents to pull on. So it might just snap off the part of the cable which is finally at the bottom.

Unless, of course, you're Dutch.  Then you just move the ocean out of the way and have all the dry land you want.

Re: anchor depth: If you make the cable exactly the depth of your ocean (and solve any problems related to weight and strength), you'll never actually get it to the bottom. If you make it longer, anchor it, and then tension it, you'll drag the ship to a watery grave long before you get it straight. [...]

[...] If you make the cable several times as long as the anchor depth, like seems to be recommended on a quick search, that's all well and good if the anchor depth is a couple of kilometers: so you're floating around a region the size of a city, big deal. But if the anchor depth is 1600km, you're floating around a region the size of the Indian Ocean.

This could be combined with strong ocean currents, to prevent people from building a floating base that have engines to avoid drift.

re anchor: how about anchor/cable eating sea monsters. Huge crabs that roam around on the bottom of the ocean and just eat the anchors by accident and when they slurp up the cable while happily munching the ship/base gets dragged down, leading to ships having to discard the achor. After a few 1600km cable anchors were lost this way, the people just stopped trying to anchor.

@bta: This planet is the dirty little secret of the Dutch. They have to put all that water somewhere. Did you just build an anchor line 1600 km down? Too bad, the Dutch just poured in another kilometer.

@MSalters I think you just accidently solved the problem about what they are fighting over.  It's a dumping world.  With a watery surface they can dump limitless amounts of compressed garbage, slag, waste water, etc. into the ocean and it can just sink for miles

Because of Jhai Gulud, the great sea worms of the ocean. Their parasites concentrate a narcotic substance which is vital to the maintenance of interstellar portals to other worlds, but the incomprehensibly enormous beasts attack and destroy any objects that don't continuously move around.
Sail without ceasing so you don't attract the worm!
The lice must flow!

Okay, don't actually just write Dune. But that's the idea. You're writing fantasy: the solutions to your worldbuilding problems can be fantastical incentives and constraints.

Bless the Salter and his fishes, Bless the Rise and fall of his tides, May his voyage calm the storms, may he keep the seas for his people.

while I agree with Vilarinof, that "use your fantasy" isn't a full answer I still think this has some merit: tying the problems of building sea bases to the incentive to be on that planet in the first place makes for a more coherent worldbuilding. Ofcourse in the real world a lot of stuff isn't interconnected but in stories and worlds it makes comprehending the world and keeping all the details in mind much easier, both for the author AND the audience.

"Sea creatures that attack fixed structures" seems like a perfectly valid science fiction answer to me - no less believable than the portals necessary for this plot. Maybe they're smaller sea worms that don't swim but can crawl up anchoring cables and dissolve metal with their secretions.

A world of shallow seas in a close orbit, or just around a hot star, would be subject to massive storms (beyond anything we see in our modern world), constantly, as the ocean surface temperatures stay at or above 40°C. Ships are mobile; they can move out of the way of oncoming hypercanes, possibly even weather the edges of them at sea. On the other hand large, stationary, objects, like cities, really anything anchored to the seabed, can't get clear, and in fact it will be very hard to build anything stationary in the first place. Storms are going to batter any large floating structures if they're in any way rigid. If the oceans are shallow enough storm driven wave activity would even make subsurface settlements untenable.

Agree, also worth noting that without solid, stable land masses to make orbital launches from there is unlikely to be satellite coverage, making weather forecasting reliant on (probably short-lived) buoys and balloons.  Combined with the energetic weather systems, the best forecasts will probably only be reliable a few days out, the weather a week in the future could be anything.

@KerrAvon2055: Orbital launches can be made from shipboard, though.

Wouldn't stop ocean bases that aren't anchored to the seabed (but instead merely float on the sea), though.  Or, for that matter, ones that can submerge themselves to escape weather, either.

@Vikki No wave length stops you building large unanchored structures, they get buckled in storms. As I noted the sea has to be fairly deep for submergence to help you weather large storm swells etc... if the oceans are Coral Sea shallow then dropping to the seabed doesn't give much, if any protection.

@Ash: Large ships already exceed wave length without issues; it's just a matter of building the structure sufficiently-strongly.

@Vikki Yes relatively long, narrow, ships designed to take waves head-on exceed wave length, and even they buckle occasionally especially when hit by a rogue, a wide top-heavy structure that can't face into the oncoming waves is going to get hammered flat.

@Ash: Just gotta build it stronger to hold up to big waves.

@Vikki Squarer too, the structures need to be huge enough that they can't capsize regardless of what direction they're hit from and strong enough that it doesn't matter by what. In shallow waters (the basic premise of this answer and I mean count shells from the surface shallow, otherwise the point about it not being safe on the bottom either doesn't apply), safe draft depth is very limited, especially when dealing with 10m or more of storm surge regularly. You can't keep small components safe, you'd need a huge floating structure built between one storm and the next. Mass limits strength.

@AlexP made a good point in the comments and it has bearing on answering the question. The reason no-one builds bigger structures on this world may well be economic rather than physical i.e. there is simply nothing of enough value to reward such an investment.
A fleet of ships may be sufficient to make some sort of ideologically driven territorial claim on the world but large scale seasteading is far more expensive in terms of time, material and highly skilled labour. A water world probably doesn't have anything that makes that kind of investment of time and resources worthwhile, especially in the earliest years. Later the world may be worth investing in if the seabed is found to be mineral rich and/or introduced fish stocks become a profitable proposition.
If the world diverged from "Earth prime" not too long ago native lifeforms may be of some value beyond sport hunting, however there is a strong argument for little-to-no complex life due to a lack of nutrient cycling without subaerial weathering of exposed landmasses.

The waters on Alternate Earth could have higher levels of valuable resources in them. Earth water has Gold dissolved in it at a low concentration of several Parts Per Billion (PPB).
Your planet could have substantially higher levels of Gold that makes it economically viable to extract.
On Earth, there are areas with higher concentrations up to 45 PPB.
If you had fixed locations of higher concentrations on Alternate Earth, it would make sense to set up a base there and defend it.
However, if there were instead high concentration Currents that are constantly drifting around Alternate Earth, they could be followed (and fought over).
Strain plausibility and make currents that have such high concentration that it visibly shimmers for an added aesthetic of the Pirates fighting over Golden Water.
It also doesn't have to be Gold, it could have a higher concentration of Heavy water (which is super valuable for nuclear fusion reactors, and some nuclear Fission Reactors).
Extracting the Heavy Water would be worth it if the concentrations are high enough.

Or switch the gold for something more viable for industrial processes, maybe platinum or cobalt. Depends which way you'd want to take the setting, i guess.

Indeed @nick . It could also be uranium for nuclear fission power, or even a complex combination of different chemicals in different concentrations in different places.
That would set up for different motivations for the various factions.
If everyone is chasing Gold, could get stale.
Maybe some people are after fuel, others after riches, others are after after something they need for agriculture?

Strong deep water currents
Deep water currents, called thermohaline circulation.

Winds drive ocean currents in the upper 100 meters of the ocean’s surface. However, ocean currents also flow thousands of meters below the surface. These deep-ocean currents are driven by differences in the water’s density, which is controlled by temperature (thermo) and salinity (haline). This process is known as thermohaline circulation.
In the Earth's polar regions ocean water gets very cold, forming sea ice. As a consequence the surrounding seawater gets saltier, because when sea ice forms, the salt is left behind. As the seawater gets saltier, its density increases, and it starts to sink. Surface water is pulled in to replace the sinking water, which in turn eventually becomes cold and salty enough to sink. This initiates the deep-ocean currents driving the global conveyor belt.

On your world, the ocean is deep enough that ocean layers are defined to a greater degree by both temperature and salinity, allowing for more dangerous thermohaline circulation. The result is the ability to sail ships on the surface, which has Earth-normal or near Earth-normal currents, but the inability to establish underwater bases because the deep currents make the bases unstable.

Singleton waves
If you are unaware, these are large scale waves that exist on this Earth, occasionally breaking up ships, also known as rogue waves. A wave like this can reach up to 30 meters in height, and several hundred miles long; if such a wave would hit an ocean base it'll get bent due to uneven load on its edges and the middle, and cave in and sink as a result. Ocean-based bases are usually slow or even drifting or anchored, so they can't easily avoid an oncoming singleton. A smaller ship, especially a military one, would not give in as easy, and can also maneuver itself to face the singleton and thus minimize the damage taken instead of plain sinking.
There might be some external circumstances required for the planet to generate such waves, most likely a moon and an axial tilt is required, but since you can depict any planet as your portal's target, just declare it being able to generate such waves, and settle there.
As a side note, a planet completely covered with oceans will develop really strong winds by itself, because there will be no mountains to slow them down (hello Roaring 40s and a wind-driven water current in our southern hemisphere), to the point that aircraft carriers would not be able to safely land their aircraft, or plain become unstable from the wind load and topple over. Also any ship would be the natural target for lightnings in any storm, and there should be quite a lot of them.
PS: your sea-based civilization with not a strip of land might collapse way too soon without an ability to dig down for fuel or massive supplies from "mother Earth" or other planets. You can limit the supply by not allowing exact control over the portal window on destination side, and since the ship would be bouncing on waves, an open portal might carve some dents in it due to relative movement.

"I hate a Barnacle as no man ever did before."- Charles Darwin
However Darwin didn't know of the superbarnacles of γ Aquarii c.
It's sailors really surpass Darwin in that regard, since these relatively small creatures have the unfortunate trait of excreting a highly corrosive substance that quickly destroys any metal structure, while their tiny but strong claws will scratch the surface before attaching to it, making paint as a protection largely ineffective.
In other regards they behave much like terrestrial barnacles, attaching firmly to anything that slowly floats in the water, but will fail to do so in strong currents or when the object in question is constantly moving above a certain speed of some knots.
Their special adaptions might be because they evolved to attach to slow moving creatures or plants in the waters and have to overcome their defenses against this, since other stationary habitats, mostly found along coast lines, are mostly missing in this world.
Its not totally impossible to have stationary structures in the water but the amount of maintance and cleaning required makes this uneconomical.

Creating portals is destructive
If every nation can create those portals, they might appear at unknown spots around that Hydroearth but take a while to fully grow. If anything comes into contact with the not yet ready to be traversed portal, it gets destroyed - and maybe the target position can even be controlled somehow. But it would be easy to escape that position if the vessel is maneuverable and fast enough. Hence no stationary bases.
If portals are not to be created by humans, maybe Hydroearth is special because as Prime-earth it has several such portals and they fluctuate. Popping up and vanishing all over the place after a few weeks.
Nobody allows the other one to get stationary.
Since everyone is having aircraft carriers ready, their attack range is huge. Other carriers can evade easily if they want to. A stationary base (or a construction site for it) is hard to defend, therefore not a viable approach.
Problem could be if a nation decides to ally with others or otherwise send several aircraft carriers to combine them to a drifting island by using steel constructs ("bridges") - given the ocean itself is calm enough to not capsize the whole construct. It also needs to be able to defend itself from incoming missiles/aircraft attacks by other aircraft carriers.
In fact it could be possible to create such an island in this scenario, but it is a political situation why they do not permit each other to have one.
As opposed to a situation where it is impossible to create such an island in the first place - e.g. because of attacks by creatures or stormy sea conditions and other destructive forces (from the portals for example).

Without a landmass, the atmosphere and the ocean can plausibly superrotate. While atmospheric superrotation, (unless extreme) can be even beneficial, because it is a source of cheap, reliable energy, oceanic superrotation (if fast enough) means you cannot easily stay at one place, unless you anchor your fleet. And that might be difficult if the water is deep enough and the currents strong enough. This almost requires the planet to be tidally locked, but that could very well happen.
For a detailed discussion, see Zeng, Yaoxuan, and Jun Yang. "Oceanic superrotation on tidally locked planets." The Astrophysical Journal 909, no. 2 (2021): 172.

The oceans are shallow and due to a massive moon in constant flux and tides, making reefs appear and any waterbound stationary structure prone to collide into the ground "coming" up and sinking them.

Shallow oceans AND a moon means at least some tectonics, which would cause eventual eruptions and land above the water level, which is not the case with that planet.Also shallow oceans will never be shallow everywhere, thus it's not a limitation for having an ocean base, as you're perfectly able to select a place for such a base where low tide won't crash the base against the seabed.

If you make Moon 4 times closer (~100 000 km) then average tides become 4^3 = 64 times bigger - some tens meters.
I think as we increase tide power at some point stationary structures would start loosing to floating bases.
